# When installing Laravel I got an error: "./composer.json is not writable."

Tags: laravel, installation

This is the command I run:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

and this is the text and error I got after that:

```
Changed current directory to /home/dimitar/.composer
./composer.json is not writable.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and PHP 7 and Composer version 1.3.0 and running this command from my home folder.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Check the owner of composer.json.

```
ls -lh ~/.composer/composer.json
```

If it's 'root', run:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername ~/.composer/composer.json
```

While in the .composer folder, check the 'cache' folder owner.
If it's 'root', re-run above command but switch composer.json to the cache.
Otherwise, you may end up with a 'Cannot create cache directory' warning.

Comment: l believe changing the whole `.composer` file to be the owner would be the best thing. To avoid future error like when install laravel you can get into issues when the script may try to write something to like the vendor file.
`sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername .composer`

Comment: Dont need to typing `-R` flag if u try to set permissions on one file

Answer (score 5):

The error says it all, there is a problem with permissions. I guess easiest way to fix this is running this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/dimitar
```

Comment: Try `777`, but do not do this on production server.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot!! i can bring it back to 775 permissions after the installation, right?

Comment: I'm not sure mate, but you can try and if it'll brake something, do 777 again. )

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is missing in your composer file which doesn't allows Packagist to find the package of Laravel.

Put this is in your `composer.json` file and try again:

```
"repositories": {
    "packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is being ran as `vagrant` user, which hasn't enough permissions.

It can be run as www-data user:

`sudo -u www-data composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Answer (score 0):

anther case. if you are using dual boot operating system make sure other operating system is shut down/power off properly. for instance in my case if windows 10 is hibernated this error will happen to ubuntu os

Answer (score 0):

You are not the file owner, however, you can change it by typing on your console the following command

```
 sudo chown -R ~/.composer/composer.json
```

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo composer global package_name
```

Example:

```
sudo composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

your password

enter

Comment: Yes, its just a case of needing to use: sudo.

Comment: Don't run composer with sudo. It will give the plugin or whatever you're installing full access to root and that is a potential security issue.

Answer (score -6):

You can run with `sudo` privilege without change folder permission because you install in global.

Comment: Doesn't even allow.

Comment: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Everybody can see this shit after typing `sudo composer`