# Unable to create new Laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, installation

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

Create a new Laravel project

**What I'm trying:**

I've been trying to follow the [installation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#installing-laravel)

1. `sudo composer global require laravel/installer`
2. `export PATH="/home/hedwin/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

When I try to run the following command:

```
sudo Laravel new trainingLaravel
```

it returns this error:

```
sudo: laravel: command not found
```

You can see my picture for details : [Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Surh6.png)

I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks a lot for every help..

Comment: Welcome, where on that page does it say to use `sudo` to install the installer? It's `composer global require laravel/installer`

Comment: i need rights to write in ./composer.json, so output is :
"Cannot create cache directory /home/hedwin/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/hedwin/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
./composer.json is not writable.
"
but thx for this kind and usefull answer, maybe "Why did you used sudo?" will be better right ?

Comment: If you are logged in as user "hedwin" and your home directory is `/home/hedwin` you have full rights inside that folder, so there should in theory be no warnings about directories not being writable. If however, you fiddled around with using `sudo` your `.composer` directory might be owned by `root` and then in fact, the folder is not writable by user "hedwin". sudo remove the `.composer` folder and all its subfolders and `composer global require laravel/installer` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit : problem unsolved, i completely remove laravel/installer

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
```

then i redo installation in /home/hedwin/ directory :

https://gist.github.com/zunayed93/80ba8611a88623c20f9bb6c7b4e25792

but my way to add /vendor/bin dir. to the path didn't work so i follow instructions at [Laravel PHP Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376516/laravel-php-command-not-found)

"Ok, I did that and it works:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And paste

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

do `source ~/.bash_profile`
"

and finally command laravel new something works !

Answer (score 0):

found solution :

sudo chown -R hedwin ~/.composer/composer.json
sudo chown -R hedwin /home/hedwin/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/
sudo chown -R hedwin /home/hedwin/.composer/cache/files/

or :
"sudo chown -R hedwin ~/.composer/" is the same

sources :
[When installing Laravel i got an error: "./composer.json is not writable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448659/when-installing-laravel-i-got-an-error-composer-json-is-not-writable)

[Cannot create cache directory .. or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874482/cannot-create-cache-directory-or-directory-is-not-writable-proceeding-withou)